# Firebase Hosting and Custom Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to use a custom authentication strategy, and Firebase hosting? Due to the lack of server-side code support with the Hosting plan, it doesn't seem likely, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is a way to serve static assets to web visitors. It cannot run your custom code on Firebase's servers.

So the answer is indeed: no, you cannot use Firebase Hosting to mint custom JWT tokens on the Firebase servers.